# Django app which is 500 on a 404

Tags: django

I got a Django project, with 1 application in it.

If I have debug set to True, and I hit write in a url like /sdfsdfsf then it will give an error

```
Using the URLconf defined in website.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
...
The current URL, dsd, didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

I then edit the settings.py to turn off Debug, but now I get 500 error. I look in the error config and get this;

```
mod_wsgi (pid=17601): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/websites/xxxxx/website/django.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 272, in __call__
        response = self.get_response(request)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 153, in get_response
        response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in handle_uncaught_exception
        return callback(request, **param_dict)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 93, in _wrapped_view
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 30, in server_error
        t = loader.get_template(template_name) # You need to create a 500.html template.
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 157, in get_template
        template, origin = find_template(template_name)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 128, in find_template
        loader = find_template_loader(loader_name)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 95, in find_template_loader
        mod = import_module(module)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
        __import__(name)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loaders/app_directories.py", line 23, in <module>
        raise ImproperlyConfigured('ImportError %s: %s' % (app, e.args[0]))
    ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError cardir: No module named cardir
```

cardir is the name of my app in the project. However if go to a page which is not a 404 (like / or /about) the it works fine, so it can get the cardir. I feel something else is going on.

Structure;

```
# ls
cardir  django.wsgi  __init__.py  __init__.pyc  manage.py  settings.py  settings.pyc  static  templates  urls.py  urls.pyc

# cd templates/ && ls
404.html  500.html  base.html  index.html
```

Comment: is cardir inside your project ?

Comment: Yes - and as I said the app runs fine on 'real' urls like the home page and about us

Comment: do you have 500.html and 404.html templates in your templates directory, because i think thats why you are getting the 500

Comment: Yes I do, I have updated question with structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if there is not an error in 404.html. I had similar issue some time ago.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My 404 page just contains the number '404', maybe it's not valid because it's to short, thanks for the suggestion - I will check it and update.